# Link database in Windows 8 vps with domain hosted on GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, vps

I have database on my Windows 8 vps and have domain in GoDaddy and I want to link domain with my database.

So, this is my connection string:

```
Data Source=149.202.4.2xx;Initial Catalog=CallCenterNew;Integrated Security=False;User ID=bel;Password=xxxxxx;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096
```

and add login user in the database as owner but when I connect I got this issue

> Login failed for user bel

Comment: Is there a record of the login attempt in the server logs?

Comment: Verify that SQL Server login exists and that you have spelled it properly. Can you connect to the database using ssms?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by server authentication 
select Sql server and windows authentication mode